# Pivot data using multiple join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a table like this in SQL Server

| name | tems | aver |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 12 |
| a | 2 | 13.5 |
| b | 1 | 19 |
| b | 2 | 15.5 |
| c | 2 | 5 |
| d | 1 | 16.75 |

How should I have following form with join clause? Not with group by, CTE, COALESCE, Null functions, conditional aggregation and PIVOT. Case clause in only allowed in join conditions.

```
select columns
from Table T1
join Table T2 on .......................
join Table T3 on .......................
```

| name | aver1 | aver2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 12 | 13.5 |
| b | 19 | 15.5 |
| b | Null | 5 |
| d | 16.75 | Null |

Comment: Have you tried actually doing what you ask? All databases work the same here, so `table1 t1 inner join table1 t2 on t1...=t2...` works everywhere

Comment: BTW your title asks one thing while your data shows something completely different. You aren't joining anything

Comment: please avoid using image. Post your sample data as text

Comment: thanks Panagiotis Kanavos but some rows would be truncated.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend conditional aggregation:

```
select name,
    max(case when tems = 1 then aver end) as aver1,
    max(case when tems = 2 then aver end) as aver2
from mytable
group by name
```

If you insist on joining, then:

```
select t1.name, t1.aver as aver1, t2.aver as aver2
from mytable t1
inner join mytable t2 on t2.name = t1.name
and t1.tems = 1 and t2.tems = 2
```

One caveat with the above join technique is that it eliminates `name`s that do not have both `tems`, so it would not produce the result you want for your sample data. You could work around this with a `full join`, but that would incur additional complexity. The conditional aggregation is simpler.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I have work with this querry but I want to create my desired table with join

Comment: @RF1991: the answer explains that conditional aggregation is a simpler approach. Why do you specifically want to use a join?

Comment: in addition, c and d would be truncated. to have better understating in my actual table and make view in sql server

Answer (score 1):

..for join...

```
declare @t table(name varchar(10), tems smallint, aver decimal(9,2));

insert into @t(name, tems, aver)
values
('a', 1, 12),
('a', 2, 13.5),
('b', 1, 19),
('b', 2, 15.5),
('c', 2, 5),
('d', 1, 16.75);

select coalesce(t1.name, t2.name) as name, t1.aver as aver1, t2.aver as aver2
from 
(
select *
from @t
where tems = 1
) as t1
full outer join 
(
select *
from @t
where tems = 2
) as t2 on t1.name = t2.name;


select coalesce(t1.name, t2.name) as name, t1.aver as aver1, t2.aver as aver2
from @t as t1
full outer join @t as t2 on t1.name = t2.name and t1.tems = 1 and t2.tems = 2
where t1.tems = 1
or
(t1.tems is null and t2.tems=2);


select t3.name, t1.aver as aver1, t2.aver as aver2
from @t as t1
full outer join @t as t2 on t1.name = t2.name and t1.tems = 1 and t2.tems = 2
join @t as t3 on case when t1.name is null then t2.name else t1.name end = t3.name
and case when t1.name is null then 2 else 1 end = t3.tems
where t1.tems = 1
or
t1.tems is null and t2.tems=2;
```

Comment: thanks for your replay. I only want answer with join. not with case,Parentheses, max, group by and conditional aggregation. however, It is possible to use case in join

Comment: @RF1991 ..the plot thickens..what rules does the 2nd query violate?

Comment: select columns from Table T1      join  Table T2  on ....................... join Table T3 on ................................

Comment: ..@RF1991..the coalesce()? you could use a case-when-end ..there will be no parenthesis(!!) in the select, but is case allowed in the select?

Comment: case is allowed only in join conditions

Comment: @RF1991..is the number of joins limited? is it allowed to join the table more than 2 times or there has to be only one/single join?

Comment: No, the number of multiple join is unlimited.

Comment: ..@RF1991...3rd query in the answer.. (what is the reason for this sadistic requirement?) <-- rhetorical question..

Comment: My original table is more than 100000 rows and 10 columns and I want to this query to make VIEW in SQL server